# Positional Embedding in the Transformer model - does it change the word's meaning?

Tags: nlp, transformer-model

I am reading the Transformer paper, and the Positional Embeddings make me wonder a thing:

Assume that the word "cat" is pretrained to be embedded to the word vector `[2,3,1,4]`. If we use the positional encoding that turns the vector into a new one, like `[3,1,5,2]`, should not it change also the word's meaning in the word2vec matrix? Since the corpus is large, a slight change in the value can also change its meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

word2vec and Transformer treat tokens completely different.

word2vec is context-free which means `bank` is always some fixed vector from the word2vec matrix, in other words, the vector of `bank` doesn't depend on the token's position in the sentence.

On the other hand, Transformer as a input receives the tokes' embeddings and positional embeddings, to add a sense of position to the tokens. Otherwise, it relates to the text as a bag-of-words and not as a sequence.